# "SpriteRenderer does not contain a definition for SetBoneTransforms" error after downgrading Unity version

Tags: unity, c#

I built a project with Unity version 2023.3.0a and I had many problems with this version so I opened my project with version 2022.3.10f1, but I have some errors.

I tried to reimport my project packages using package manager, but I still have some errors like:

> Library PackageCacheicom.unity.2d.common@9.0.21RuntimeIntemailBridgelintemalEngineBridge ca ( 21,28 ) ror CS1061 : SpriteRenderer does not contain a definition for SetBoneTransforms and no accessible extension method " SetBone Transforme accepting a first argument of type " SpriteRenderer could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ? )

Comment: If you just started the project and it doesn't have many files in it, it might be easier to create a new project in 2022.3.10f1 and copy the files from the `Assets` folder into the new project.

Comment: Sounds like [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168878/unity-spriterenderer-error-what-i-need-to-do) is about the exact same error. I found it by entering "SpriteRenderer does not contain a definition for SetBoneTransforms" into a search engine. Googling error messages can be really helpful in solving problems.

Comment: It looks like the error message got seriously garbled when you copied/transcribed it into your question. Please take the time to review what you've posted and ensure it reads correctly in its entirety.